# Export DataFrame from Python to CSV

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have a data frame I created with my original data appended with the topics from topic modeling. I keep running into errors when trying to export the data table into `csv`.

I've tried both `csv` module and `pandas` but get errors from both.

The data table has 1765 rows so writing the file row by row is not really an option.

When using pandas, most common errors are

> DataFrame constructor not properly called!

and

> function object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Code used:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = (before.head)

df = pd.DataFrame(before.head)
df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\***\Desktop\beforetopics.csv', index = False, header=True)
print (df)
```

For the CSV module, there have been several errors such as

> iterable expected, not method

Basically, how do I export this table (screenshot attached) into a csv file?

[image: Screenshot of Table]

Comment: what error are you getting? And pandas has [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for saving a [Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) to csv

Comment: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: You should update your question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `to_csv` function:

```
before.to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

If you need extra options, you can check the documentation from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Answer (score 1):

What is the command that you're trying to run?

Try this:

`dataframe.to_csv('file_name.csv')`

Or if it is the unicode error that you're coming across,

Try this:

`dataframe.to_csv('file_name.csv', header=True, index=False, encoding='utf-8')`

Since your dataframe's name is `before`,

Try this:

`before.to_csv('file_name.csv', header=True, index=False, encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: That worked. Not surprising since I finally used the correct name for my data frame...I think it's time to finally take a break! I'm starting to lose my mind....THANK YOU!

Comment: Haha! You're welcome. All the best for your future works!